# How to get Client ID of Textbox which is Gridview EditItemTemplate for transalate textbox value to marathi using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, google-translate

I am using masterpage include webform page in that i want gridview textbox id in my javascript function

I want client ID of Textbox which is present in Gridview in EditItemTemplate mode for translation purpose at the time of edit mode of gridview.

I want that Textbox client ID in Javascript function.

How can I solve this?

This is my code

```
This the script which i am using for translate
`<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        google.load("elements", "1", { packages: "transliteration" });

            function onLoad() {

                var options = {
                    //Source Language
                    sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
                    // Destination language to Transliterate
                    destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.MARATHI],
                    shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
                    transliterationEnabled: true
                };

                var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);


            control.makeTransliteratable(['<%=txtFromWhomeRecieved.ClientID%>']);

            }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);`
```

this is my gridview

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id"  
                        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                        OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" CellPadding="1" Height="30px" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" CssClass="auto-style2" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="6">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Inward No " readonly="true"  >
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000066" Font-Size="Small"  />
                            <ItemStyle />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AdminRecieved_Date" HeaderText="Inward Date"  DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}" readonly="true">
                            <ItemStyle  />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name From Whome Recieved">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFromWhomeRecieved" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromWhomeRecieved")%>'   ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromWhomeRecieved" name="txtWhome" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromWhomeRecieved")%>' />      

    ` </EditItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField></asp:GridView>'
```